# NLog file archive behavior not as expected

Tags: nlog

NLog archive behavior is not working as expected. NLog version used: 4.7.9

```xml
 <target name="traceLog" xsi:type="file" fileName="log-${shortdate}.1.log"
          archiveFileName="log-${shortdate}.{#}.log"
          archiveAboveSize="1280" // 10kb 
          archiveNumbering="Sequence"
          concurrentWrites="false"
          keepFileOpen="true"
          openFileCacheTimeout="30"
          maxArchiveFiles="5">
```

Output with inconsistent size though achieve expected after every 10kb size

[image]

Also,

1. want reuse the old achieve file but it delete those old archives(like 0, 1) instead and
2. also wanted to number archive starts with 1 instead of 0.

How to achieve these requirements with NLog?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just do this:

```xml
<target name="traceLog" xsi:type="file" fileName="log-${shortdate}.log"
        archiveAboveSize="1280"
        maxArchiveFiles="5"
        keepFileOpen="true"
        concurrentWrites="false"
        openFileCacheTimeout="30">
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archive-old-log-files

Notice if you mix "Dynamic FileName Archive Logic" (`log-${shortdate}.1.log`)  with "Static FileName Archive Logic" (`archiveFileName="..."`), then it will not work well. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#dynamic-vs-static-archive-logic